# Minimise read and write system calls in C

Tags: c, file-io, io, system-calls

I'm a computer science student and I must do a practical in C on the Inputs/outputs of a file system. In fact I have to code the Inputs/outputs of a file system. I have to create functions : openIt, closeIt, readIt and writeIt.
For the moment I have that :

```
int readIt(void *p, unsigned int size, unsigned int nbelem, FILE *f) {
  printf("Read of %d char … \n", nbelem);
  if (f->mode != 'L'){
    printf("ERROR : file not open in read mode. \n");
    return -1;
  }
  int sizeRead = 0;
  for (int i  = 0; i < nbelem; i++){
    if ((sizeRead = read(f->fd,p,size)) < 0){
      printf("ERROR : read impossible. \n");
    }
  }
  return sizeRead;
}
```

with this file structure :

```
#define MAX 10

struct _ES_FICHIER {
  char mode ;
  char buffer[MAX];
  int index ;
  int fd ;
};
```

But in fact the purpose of this practical is to minimise read, write, open and close system calls. Yet I've done a loop so it's not really optimised, I have much too much read.

My readIt and writeIt functions are used in a file test.c like that :

```
FILE *f1;
FILE *f2;
char c;

while (readIt (&c, 1, 1, f1) == 1) {
   writeIt (&c, 1, 1, f2);
}
```

In my file 1 and file 2, I only have strings like : « abcd ».

I don't use the buffer of my file structure for the moment. It must contain the content of the file to read and a read() have to be used use only if need be. For example when the buffer is full or when the file has been entirely read.

Basically : We put all the content of the file in the buffer -> We call read to store this buffer in p.

But I don't understand how to get the contents of the file without a lot of read() calls. I'm really stuck at this precise point.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: File I/O is typically buffered. Have you compared your approach to something "more optimised"? If not, read and  write  chunks (e.g. 1000 bytes) and compare the results.

Comment: Are you sure that `readIt()` is supposed to return the size of only the last read element?